# Unable obtain JDBC Connection with oracle 19c in java 1.8

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I'm getting below exception whenever I try to start my java application

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator  - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

1406 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
6359 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper  - Unable obtain JDBC Connection
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:388)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:381)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:427)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOSESSKEY(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:390)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:356)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:145)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper.executeIdTableCreationStatements(IdTableHelper.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.prepare(AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at com.company.frontend.tracking.TrackingContext.<init>(TrackingContext.java:24)
    at com.company.frontend.tracking.TrackingContext.getInstance(TrackingContext.java:29)
    at com.company.process.CorrespondenceFTPInputProcess.<init>(Myapplication.java:23)
    at com.company.frontend.Myapplication.preRun(Myapplication.java:41)
    at com.company.frontend.ProcessApp.run(ProcessApp.java:275)
    at com.company.frontend.Myapplication.main(CorrespondenceFTPRouterIn.java:88)
6409 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator  - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
[main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[main] INFO org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean - Initializing EhCache CacheManager
02/15/23  06:37:10  Initializing FTPInputProcess
Database connection unavailable
```

versions of project I'm using
Java version:java 1.8
database is oracle 19c.

The thing I have tried
I updated the ojdbc5 jar to ojdbc6 but still no luck, Can someone please assist me with this problem?

Comment: You need ojdbc8 or ojdbc10 according to this page: https://www.oracle.com/sg/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html

Comment: And since you're on Java 8, you should use ojdbc8.

Comment: If you are unable to upgrade Java and JDBC, you can set parameter SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=11 in sqlnet.ora on the datbase server. Upgrade highly recommended, though.

Comment: You should also check version of password hash stored with your DB user: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56531594/836215