# ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol with Testcontainers Oracle-XE (via JDBC URL) and Spring Framework 5

Tags: java, spring, oracle, testcontainers

I am trying to set up Testcontainers to perform integration tests for a project that uses Spring 5.3 and Oracle 12C, but I am getting the error "ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol" every time I try to run a test.

The production database is accessed using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, configured like this:

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="jndiName" value="${connectionDataSource}" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate" id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate">
     <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

`connectionDataSource` is just a property with the value jdbc/myproject, which points to a conecction configured in the application server (Bea Weblogic 12.2).

I am trying to configure the test datasource in a separated file test-applicationContext-resources.xml like this:

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
                      transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:tc:oracle:21-slim-faststart:///myproject?TC_INITSCRIPT=/myproject.sql"/>
    <property name="username" value="myproject"/>
    <property name="password" value="myproject"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate" id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

And then I try to execute this test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-applicationContext-resources.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
@Testcontainers
class MyProjectTest {
    @Autowired
    MyProjectDAO myProjectDAO;

    @Test
    void test() {
        int userNumber = myProjectDAO.countUsers();
        assertEquals(1, userNumber);
    }
}
```

but I am getting the mentioned error.

I tried removing username and password properties from the configuration, and also the driverClassName property, but did not change a thing.

The JDBC driver that I am using in production is:

```
testRuntime group: 'com.oracle', name: 'ojdbc', version: '6'
```

not sure if this could be the cause.

Doing some searches it looks like people having this problem could solve it setting `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8` but I am not sure how to do that with a Testcontainers image.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56531594/836215 . You need to keep in sync: JDBC driver version, Database version and also password hash format stored in database. Your error indicates, database could not find proper password hash for this user.

Answer (score 0):

@ibre5041 is right. I solved it just by changing the ojdbc to version 8:

testRuntime group: 'com.oracle.database.jdbc', name: 'ojdbc8', version: '23.3.0.23.09'