Getting error "ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception" with custom DataSourceFactory
I have extended the BasicDataSourceFactory (of [Apache Commons] DBCP) as follows:
public class MyFactory extends BasicDataSourceFactory {

    public MyFactory () {}

    @Override
    public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable<?, ?> environment) throws SQLException {
        return super.getObjectInstance(obj, name, nameCtx, environment);
    }   
}

I'm using this class as factory in my Resources's definition in the context.xml:
<Resource name="MyResource"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        factory="path.to.my.factory.MyFactory"
        username="myusername"
        password="mypassword"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        url="myUrl"
        maxTotal="8"
        maxIdle="4"
        defaultAutoCommit="true"
        removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"
        removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL">
</Resource>

Then I try to retrieve MyResource:
Context envCtx = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("MyResource");
ds.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);

The DataSource seems to create ok, because ds has all the properties defined in the context.xml (user, password, url, driver...). BUT when I call getConnection, I get the ORA-28040 error.
HOWEVER, if I remove the line factory="path.to.my.factory.MyFactory" from the DataSource resource's definition (I assume it will use a generic factory), getConnection works fine. What am I missing?
I'm using ojdbc8/JDK8 with an Oracle 19 database, which are supposed to be compatible, according to Oracle documentation.
I've tried with a couple of the latest versions of ojdbc8, so my pom.xml will look like:
<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc8 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>23.5.0.24.07</version>
</dependency>

Or:
<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc8 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>23.2.0.0</version>
</dependency>

I'm using Apache Tomcat 8.5.76.

If you ask for which BasicDataSourcefactory I'm extending, it's: org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory

Just in case anybody asks why I don't use the generic factory if it works. The reason is that I will need to perform additional actions before getting the connection.

which version of ojdbc8 ? provide the maven/gradle artifact definition you are using

Yes, it's a Maven web app.

Take the [tour] and read [ask]. When a comment asks for more details, you should [edit] your question and add those details. You should not post question details in a comment. By the way, what Web application server are you using? Is it Tomcat?

Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56531594/836215. Your password in database was hashed using algorithm your JDBC driver does not support or refuses to use. Check version of password stored in database. So your JDBC driver is compatible, the way how your password was hashed is not.

Will check the password version (as soom as the DB admin give me permission to query on the dba_users table).

Still waiting for my DB Admin's response... Please, don't close the topic. The issue is not solved yet.
